# How do I turn a .py file into an application on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

[I know this question has been asked multiple times but I am still having trouble finding an option that works for me]

I am using replit.com to write my python code.

I made a program in python, but I want to turn it into an executable application (not a .exe as I am on mac). I saw multiple people use py2app but it doesn't work for me (probably due to the fact I am using an Online IDE). I also tried PyCharm, but when I write: "pip install py2app" to import the package, it just says that it doesn't know the command "pip".

The name of the file is: "main.py"

Here is my code in case it helps (it is pretty messy and confusing):

```
from tkinter import *
import math

root = Tk()
root.title('Minion Profit Calculator')

#Variables#
money = 0
actionT = 0
itemPerAc = 0
unitPr = 0
hasDia = IntVar()
diaSprMoney = 0
money1h = 0

#Labels#
acTime = Label(root, text="Action Time:")
itemAc = Label(root, text="Item/Action:")
unitPrice = Label(root, text="Unit Price:")
diaSpread = Label(root, text="Diamond Spreading:")
profitDis = Label(root, text="Profit (/24h):")
profit = Label(root, text="")
profit1Dis = Label(root, text="Profit (/1h)")
profit1 = Label(root, text="")

#Input Fields#
acTimeIn = Entry(root)
itemAcIn = Entry(root)
unitPriceIn = Entry(root)


#Checkboxes#
diaSpreadBox = Checkbutton(root, variable=hasDia, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)

#Click Event#
def isClicked():
  
  actionT = float(acTimeIn.get())
  itemPerAc = float(itemAcIn.get())
  unitPr = float(unitPriceIn.get())

  money = (86400/actionT*itemPerAc*unitPr)
  diaSprMoney = (138240/actionT)

  if (hasDia.get() == 1):
    money = money + diaSprMoney

  money = math.trunc(money)
  money1h = (money / 24)
  money1h = math.trunc(money1h)

  #Add $ before the number
  money = str(money)
  money1h = str(money1h)

  money = ("$"+money)
  money1h = ("$"+money1h)

  profit.configure(text=money)
  profit1.configure(text=money1h)

#Buttons#
cal = Button(root, text="Calculate", command=isClicked)

#Grid Placing#
acTime.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
itemAc.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
unitPrice.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
diaSpread.grid(row=3, column = 0)
profitDis.grid(row=5)
profit.grid(row=5, column=1)
profit1Dis.grid(row=6)
profit1.grid(row=6, column=1)

acTimeIn.grid(row=0, column=1)
itemAcIn.grid(row=1, column=1)
unitPriceIn.grid(row=2, column=1)

diaSpreadBox.grid(row=3, column=1)

cal.grid(row=4, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop
```

Comment: Add a shebang and make the file executable with `chmod`.

Comment: I suspect you're running into one of the limitations of online IDEs…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to move your code into a new python file on your machine. I don't think it's possible to do this using replit.

You have to download pip for you to do this properly. You can download pip [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#supported-methods).

Once you have pip downloaded, you can use the [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) library to package Python programs as standalone executables. It works on Windows, Linux, and Mac.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5458250/14771613) answer for more details.

If you want to stick with `py2app`, just run `pip install py2app` in your terminal once you have pip downloaded.